# Why is my SAS output giving me different results than my proc means statement?

Tags: sas

my proc means data is just how I want it. But, when I try to output the data to an excel it does not look the same. How do I fix this?

```
/*Means average value by state*/
proc means data = merged;
class statename state;
var valueh;
output out = statedata1 MEAN = valueh;
run;

/*Export the Data*/
proc export data = statedata outfile= '/home/...' dbms= xlsx replace;
run;

proc print data = statedata;
run;
```

The data appears fine but when I output it to an excel it is separating my state and statename variables instead of keeping them combined. Attached is a picture the proc means output as well as the proc print after I exported the data.
[image][image]

Comment: You printed a different dataset than you asked PROC MEANS to create.  statedata  vs statedata1

Comment: You probably want to add the NWAY option to your PROC MEANS as well, unless you want the different levels of summary.

Answer (score 0):

The dataset produced does not not need to look like the REPORT produced.
In particular the default for the report is to only include the results that use all of the class variables.  And the default for the generated dataset is to include the summary for all possible combinations of the class variables.  With 2 class variables there are four possible combinations (which reflected in the _TYPE_ variable).  Overall (none), Each one separately and both together.

If you want the report in your Excel file why not use ODS EXCEL.

```
/*Export the Report*/
ods excel file='/home/...';
proc means data = merged;
  class statename state;
  var valueh;
run;
ods excel close;
```

If you only want the results that include both CLASS variables then you could add the NWAY option to the PROC MEANS statement.

```
proc means data = merged nway;
```

Or use the TYPES or WAYS statement to control which combinations are produced.

Or just filter in the export.

```
proc export data = statedata(where=(_type_=3))
  outfile= '/home/...' dbms= xlsx replace
;
run;
```